# Add Infinity Scroll Down in Joomla

Tags: joomla, scroll, infinite-loop

How do I integrate Jquery code for Infinity/Autopager Scroll down in Joomla. And If possible the scroller to work on Chosen Articles.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add jQuery into your joomla made site then it is easy to load a jquery file like:

1. Add the following codes into your index.php file you will find this file in your template directory like : `joomla/templates/rhuk_milkyway/index.php` now simple open it and add the following code after `<link>` tab

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

now before starting your own jquery codes it is must to make your codes without conflicting with mootools and other, and for this just simple add `jQuery.noConflict();` and place `jQuery` instead of `$` for example:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
// now your codes like
jQuery('#someid').each(function(i, e){});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Jogesh, thanx for your quick response. now, the action i need to achieve is to enable endless scroll down like the one on a wordpress plugin. Is this possible on Joomla?

Comment: @user1180989 can you please show some website url for that, or do you want something like the data will show(fadein) when the page scroll down??

Comment: @user1180989 in which tag it is endless, its just show the `backtop` button?? do you want something like this??

Comment: @user1180989 ofcause you can load the specific image like that you show, with the `.hover()`event and redirect the page on the specific article of the relevant image with jquery..

Comment: Ok i get you....but am haven't still got a way to trigger Endless scrolling....Images lazily loading.